# Validation Errors when using multiple IsEmbedded references

Tags: visual-studio-2019, dsl, modeling

I'm encountering a problem when trying to create a DSL for use in Visual Studio IDE.
I'm trying to use Visual Studio Modeling SDK to generate a Visual Studio Extension allowing for the drawing of Fault Trees<sup>[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fault_tree_analysis)</sup> and Reliability Block Diagrams<sup>[2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reliability_block_diagram)</sup> plus also some Markov Models<sup>[3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain)</sup> for reliability analysis.

As part of this I'd like two have two 'things', a Gate, and an Event, which both have an output port. As the OutPort would not be shared with other objects, and is really inherent in the object itself, I've tried to make this IsEmbedded.

However the Validation Engine appears to complain when I have this IsEmbedded and 1..1 multiplicity.  With a Validation Error that it must be 0..1 multiplicity.  Now that I have configured this however, I'm still getting the same Validation Error.

I did post this on the MSDN Visual Studio Forum<sup>[4](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/02a8d54b-58d9-4dd3-893d-a5bd97d838ba/modeling-sdk-dsl-project-validation-errors-when-using-multiple-isembedded-references?forum=vsx)</sup>, however with no success (I was redirected to Stack Overflow).

Does anyone know of good resources for the Modeling SDK?
Whilst the DSL platform appears to be well suited to do what I'm after, if there is another way of getting the Toolbox drag/drop and node layout capability (easily) within Visual Studio then I'm happy to hear about it.

[image: Visual Studio 2019 Validation Error]